# How can I use decode statement in a loop in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, google-bigquery

I need some help in expanding the below query statement written in Oracle to Big query, I am very new to big query and I am not aware of the syntax to use for using the same logic in BQ.

> (to_char(decode(sign(decode(to_char(c.last_updated_time  +3, 'D') ,7 , c.last_updated_time  +5 ,1 ,c.last_updated_time  +5, 2, c.last_updated_time  +5,3, c.last_updated_time  +4, c.last_updated_time  +3) -sysdate),-1,3,1)),' ') Priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we generate some sample data with `last_updated_time`. The `due_date` is several days later, depending on the day of the week. So simulation a weekend and working days. Therefore adding to the `last_updated_time` is done with `TIMESTAMP_ADD`. Since the `Interval` is
depending on the day of the week, which is a number from 1 to 7, following statement is used:

```
CASE day_of_the_week WHEN 7 then adding_value ... end
```

Next the date difference between `due_date` and today is calculated. Prio 1 is for `due_date` which are in the past. Otherwise Prio 3 is returned.
So we end up with this **BigQuery** query:

```
WITH
  tbl AS (
  SELECT * 
  from unnest(generate_timestamp_array(timestamp "2024-01-01",timestamp "2024-04-01",interval 1 day ) ) as last_updated_time
     )
SELECT *,
  IF(
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP_ADD( c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL (
      CASE EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM TIMESTAMP_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 3 DAY))
        WHEN 7 THEN 5
        WHEN 1 THEN 4
        WHEN 2 THEN 4
        WHEN 3 THEN 4
      ELSE 3
    END
      ) DAY ),current_timestamp(), DAY)
      >0,3,1) # Prio 1 if day is in past, otherwise Prio 3 
     ||' ' # convert to string with space after
       AS Priority,
  CASE
    WHEN EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM TIMESTAMP_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 3 DAY)) = 7 THEN 
      TIMESTAMP_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
    WHEN EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM TIMESTAMP_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 3 DAY)) IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 
      TIMESTAMP_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 4 DAY)
  ELSE
    TIMESTAMP_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 3 DAY)
END
  AS due_date
FROM
  tbl AS c
  order by 1
```

As you see another solution is used for the `due_date` presented. The case statement for the day of the week is done before and then date calculation is done for each case.

I also want to comment each step of the given **Oracle** query:

```
-- query with comments above each line
SELECT 
    -- convert result to string and add a space character
    TO_CHAR(
        -- The DECODE(x,1,2) function is the (CASE x when 1 then 2 end) structure in BigQuery
        DECODE(
            -- This SIGN function returns -1 if the value is negative, 0 if zero, and 1 if positive
            SIGN(
                -- This DECODE function calculates a due date based on the last_updated_time and this date of the week
                DECODE(
                    -- TO_CHAR function converts last_updated_time + 3 days into the day of the week
                    TO_CHAR(c.last_updated_time + 3, 'D'),  
                    -- If day of the week is Saturday (7), add 5 days
                    7, c.last_updated_time + 5,
                    -- If day of the week is Sunday (1), add 5 days
                    1, c.last_updated_time + 5,
                    -- If day of the week is Monday (2), add 5 days
                    2, c.last_updated_time + 5,
                    -- If day of the week is Tuesday (3), add 4 days
                    3, c.last_updated_time + 4,
                    -- For all other days, add 3 days
                    c.last_updated_time + 3
                ) - SYSDATE -- Subtracting current system date
            ),
            -- If the result is negative, return prio 3 (due date is today or in the future)
            -1, 3,
            -- If the result is positive or zero, return prio 1 (due date is in the past)
            1
        ),
        ' ' -- Convert the result into a character string with a space character
    ) AS Priority
FROM tbl AS c;
```

Comment: In Oracle, `to_char(date_value, 'D')` returns different values depending on the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting for the user's session. If the user running the query is in most European countries then a date on Monday returns 1; if the user is in America then Sunday dates return 1; if the user is in the Middle-East then Saturday dates return 1 and if the user is in Bangladesh then Friday dates return 1. I'm not sure where the OP is in the world or whether they have users running their query in different territories but you may need to convert that behaviour as well.

Comment: Given this, your commented code is only correct if the OP is running the code in a session with an `NLS_TERRITORY` setting where Sunday is considered the first day of the week (for example, America). Anywhere else in the world your commented code is incorrect as the days of the week would be shifted by one or two days. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/32W4gndM)

Comment: Thank you for the solution however, there one issue my 'last_updated_time' field is in string format and not datetime sorry forgot to mention that in beginning

Comment: For converting a string into a timestamp (UTC) use `parse_timestamp` and provide the formation string. Please see the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp). Without providing sample data as an example, the task cannot be solved. It is huge difference from "2024-02-29" to "29/02/2024".

Comment: this is the error I get 'Failed to parse input string "2020-05-01 16:07:30"'
Here is a sample data
last_updated_time
2023-06-07 13:27:13
2023-06-09 08:29:04
2023-07-11 10:53:48
2023-07-11 10:57:31
2023-07-11 10:58:46
2023-05-13 02:22:32
2023-07-01 08:36:42
2023-07-01 08:48:06
2023-07-01 09:08:48
2023-07-04 08:42:24

Comment: using this code TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP_ADD(parse_timestamp('%c',c.last_updated_time)

Comment: '%c' is the wrong format, please see the example of the doc `PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%c", "Thu Dec 25 07:30:00 2008")`. You need `SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%F %T","2020-05-01 16:07:30")`